# Fourier transform of $\left|x\right|\exp(-t\left|x\right|)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I need to compute the Fourier transform of the following function:
$f(x)=|x| \exp(-t|x|)$ where $t>0, \ t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Since this is an even function only the real part of the Fourier transform will contribute so the integral becomes:

$\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}x\exp(-t x)\cos(\lambda x) dx$

which according to my textbook can be rewritten by using the following rule:

$\mathcal{F}[x^nf(x)](\lambda)=i^n \frac{d^n}{d\lambda^n} \mathcal{F}[f](\lambda)$

so that we have:

$\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}i \frac{d}{d\lambda} \left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-t x)\cos(\lambda x)dx\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{-2\lambda it}{(\lambda^2+t^2)^2}$

However this is not equivalent to the first integral:

$\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}x\exp(-t x)\cos(\lambda x) dx=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{t^2-\lambda^2}{(\lambda^2+t^2)^2}$

Which is the right answer. You can arrive at the same answer by using the rule from the textbook but replacing the cosine term with an exponential and taking two times the real part like this:

$\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\text{Re}\left[i \frac{d}{d\lambda} \left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-t x)\exp(-i\lambda x)dx\right)\right]=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{t^2-\lambda^2}{(\lambda^2+t^2)^2}$

Why does the rule from the textbook not work in the case where I'm using $\cos(\lambda x)$? Is that not equivalent to taking the real part since I've just thrown away the $i\sin(\lambda x)$ term of the integral because it's going to be an odd function integrated over a symmetric interval so it'll be 0 anyways?

Answer (score 3):

Your original formula does work. The problem is that the added $x$ term turns an even integrand $|x|e^{-t|x|}$ into the odd one $x|x|e^{-t|x|}$. And that also makes sense directly because $\frac{d}{d\lambda}\cos(\lambda x)=-x\sin(\lambda x)$. The error comes in thinking that the derivative is going remain a Fourier cosine transform instead of switching to a Fourier sine transform.

For example,
$$
    \frac{d}{ds}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|x|t}e^{-isx}dx
   = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(-ix)e^{-|x|t}e^{-isx}dx
$$
The integral on the left may be written as a cosine transform, while the integral on the right is a sign transform. So, without changing the derivative, but rewriting the integrals only,
$$
    \frac{d}{ds}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-|x|t}\cos(sx)ds
  =-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-|x|t}\sin(sx)dx
$$
And, you can see that the second identity also follows by interchanging the derivative with respect to $s$ and the derivative with respect to $s$. You can compute these
\begin{align}
   \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-|x|t}\cos(sx)ds &=\Re \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xt}e^{isx}dx\\
   &= \Re \left(\left.\frac{1}{is-t}e^{x(is-t)}\right|_{x=0}^{\infty}\right) \\
   &= \Re \frac{1}{t-is} = \Re \frac{(t+is)}{t^2+s^2}=\frac{t}{t^2+s^2}.
\end{align}
That gives
$$
   \int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-xt}\sin(sx)dx = -\frac{d}{ds}\frac{t}{t^2+s^2} = \frac{2ts}{(t^2+s^2)^2}
$$
Everything seems to work out:
\begin{align}
     \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(-ix)e^{-|x|t}e^{-ixs}dx
   & = \int_{-\infty}^{0}(-ix)e^{xt}e^{-isx}dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}(-ix)e^{-xt}e^{-ixs}dx \\
   & = \left.(-ix)\frac{e^{x(t-is)}}{t-is}\right|_{-\infty}^{0}-\int_{-\infty}^{0}(-i)\frac{e^{x(t-is)}}{t-is}dx \\
   & + \left.(-ix)\left(-\frac{e^{-x(t+is)}}{t+is}\right)\right|_{0}^{\infty}
-\int_{0}^{\infty}i\frac{e^{-x(t+is)}}{t+is}dx \\
   & =\int_{-\infty}^{0}i\frac{e^{x(t-is)}}{t-is}dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}i\frac{e^{-x(t+is)}}{t+is}dx \\
   & = \left.i\frac{e^{x(t-is)}}{(t-is)^2}\right|_{x=-\infty}^{0}
   + \left. i\frac{e^{-x(t+is)}}{(t+is)^2}\right|_{0}^{\infty} \\
   & = \frac{i}{(t-is)^2}-\frac{i}{(t+is)^2} \\
   & = \frac{i(t+is)^2}{(t^2+s^2)^2}-\frac{i(t-is)^2}{(t^2+s^2)^2} \\
   & = -\frac{4st}{(t^2+s^2)^2}
\end{align}
The factor of $2$ comes from the difference in Fourier coefficients. I'll let you sort out the $-1$.

You can do the same thing when you differentiate with respect to $t$ as well.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I thought that I would get notified if someone answered. Maybe I've misunderstood you but it seems like you may have misunderstood the formula. You have to take the derivative OF the Fourier transform, you can't move the derivative inside the integral. Either way I don't really understand where you get the added $x$ from in $x|x|e^{-t|x|}$? It would be appreciated if you would expand a little on your answer.

Comment: @ChristianF.Madsen : I added a bit more for you.

Comment: Thanks for expanding although I'm still pretty unsure what you're trying to say. Especially in the second to last sentence I guess there's a typo? I also think you forgot the $i$ in the last equation. 
Anyways I think what you're saying is that I can move the derivative inside the integral so that I'm left with:

$i\left ( -i\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^{-t|x|}sin(\lambda x) dx\right) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{4 \lambda t}{(\lambda^2+t^2)^2}$ 

which is still wrong. (Btw. shouldn't the limits be from 0 to infinity?)

Comment: I see you've added a bit more, but you're still ending up with the wrong result? I'm trying to obtain something of the form $\frac{t^2-\lambda^2}{(\lambda^2+t^2)^2}$.

Comment: @ChristianF.Madsen : Time for you to modify your question to show why you expect to get that answer. I have two ways of getting a different answer, and they both agree. Check my checks. They're all there.

Comment: It said so in the exercise, specifically that I had to show that the Fourier transform of the given function was equal to some constant times that form. Additionally a lot of CAS programs can evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}x\exp(-t x)\cos(\lambda x) dx$ including Wolfram Alpha and the answer is $\frac{t^2-\lambda^2}{(t^2+\lambda^2)^2}$ which is what I'm trying to obtain. It's clear that the function is even so we don't need to compute the integral containing $i\sin(\lambda x)$ since it'll be 0.

Comment: @ChristianF.Madsen : I mentioned before that when you take the derivative with respect to $\lambda$, the $\cos(\lambda x)$ changes to $-x\sin(\lambda x)$, which is not going to give you the integral with $x\cos(\lambda x)$. The derivative formulas still hold, though.

Comment: It doesn't seem to change the outcome, whether I move the derivative inside the integral or not I get $\int_{0}^{\infty}-x\sin(\lambda x)\exp(-tx)=\frac{-2\lambda t}{(\lambda^2+t^2)^2}$ which isn't what I want. Moving the derivative inside the integral also makes that rule kind of redundant, you want to reduce the integrand but when you move the derivative inside the integral you get the factor of x out again which was the very thing you wanted to use the rule to get rid of.

Comment: @ChristianF.Madsen : Once you start with the integral you want compute, whether that be with a cos or a sin, then back up to the integral with the opposite trig function so that the derivative of the backed-out one is the one you want to compute. It works.

Comment: I'm not sure what that meant, but I think you're trying to argue that the formula works, and I've seen proof's of it so I'm sure it works, and it has served me well 99% of the time. The question here is **why** doesn't it work in this particular case? As far as I know it **should** work here, but it clearly doesn't.